# Blazor Hosted Client Login Success but Subsequent Calls Show Not Authenticated

Tags: api, authentication, blazor-webassembly, identity

I am following a tutorial [Custom Authentication in Blazor WebAssembly – Detailed](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/authentication-in-blazor-webassembly/). I created a new Hosted Blazor application with `.net7` and using `Individual User Accounts`.

I want to be able to create my own razor components for Login, Register, etc., instead of using the scaffolded razor pages in the API. So I created a UserAuth Controller with endpoints for Login, LogOut, etc.

I can login and the result is Succeeded. When I later call the CurrentUserInfo endpoint, the User is not authenticated and has no claims. I have seeded claims for the user. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequest request)
{            
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName ??="");
    if (user == null) return BadRequest("User does not exist");
    var singInResult = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password ??="", false);
    if (!singInResult.Succeeded) return BadRequest("Invalid password");
    //await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, request.RememberMe);
    
// success here
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(request.UserName, request.Password, isPersistent: request.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false); 
    return Ok();
}
```

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet(Name ="currentuserinfo")]
public CurrentUser CurrentUserInfo()
{
    return new CurrentUser
    {
        IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, // false
        UserName = User.Identity?.Name,
        Claims = User.Claims // 0 claims
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Type, c => c.Value)
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?